# Invalid argument in foreach loop using a model

Tags: laravel-5.4

Hey I am making a code in which I m using foreach loop but its giving me error of invalid argument.

Loop of my code is

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    foreach(Auth::user()->User as $role){
            if($role->role == 'doctor')
            {
                return $next($request);   
            }
        }
        return redirect('');
}
```

And the model is

```
 <?php

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

 class User extends Authenticatable
 {
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

}

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a foreach on Auth:user(). If you want to validate the role of a user, you can get the user object that is doing the request and validate the role, for example:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if($request->user()->rol == 'admin'){
        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect('/something');
}
```